# Finish a method with throwing exception rather than return

Tags: c#, error-handling

So I have this method:

```
public string SaveImage(AppConfig imagePath, string ImageNameFilter)
{
    if (selectedFileName == null)
    {
        return null;//No image is selected - return
    }
    string imgPath = imagePath.ConfigValue.ToString();
    string baseFileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(selectedFileName);
    string extension = Path.GetExtension(selectedFileName);

    string temp = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(selectedFileName);

    if (!baseFileName.StartsWith(ImageNameFilter))
    {
        throw new InvalidImageException("The image name must starts with  " + ImageNameFilter);
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < (int.MaxValue - 1); i++)
        {
            if (File.Exists(imgPath + "\\" + baseFileName + extension))
            {
                baseFileName = temp;
            }
            else
            {
                File.Copy(selectedFile, imgPath + "\\" + baseFileName + extension);
                return (baseFileName + extension);
            }
            baseFileName += (i).ToString();
        }
    }

    //throw new InvalidImageException("The Image was not saved");
    return null;//Should never come here - something went wrong
}
```

The problem is that the method is waiting for return at the end even though I thought I was handling all possible outcomes. Now I see that in fact `for (int i = 1; i < (int.MaxValue - 1); i++)` is one possible (even though mostly theoretical way) for the method to reach the end and maybe there are more cases that would cause reaching the end of the method before returning any result. However the compiler complains if there's no `return` but on the other side if the code reaches the end of the method this means that there's something wrong and I want to be able to handle this properly.

I user `null` at the begining for this check:

```
if (selectedFileName == null)
{
    return null;//No image is selected - return
}
```

And because ti's absolutely OK to not have an image selected I think the place where I should return `null` result is this. Which leaves with kinda no options for the other outcome - when nothing is executed and I reach the end of the method. As posted I `return null;` again, but I need to change it. I need to know that this exact scenario is taking place and I need to react accordingly.

There are two options that I can think right now - return some string that I check for or throwing an exception. But I'm not sure - is it a proper way to finish method with throwing an exception instead of using the standard `return` statement. And what do you think is the proper way to deal with this case?

Comment: According to your code: If every suggested file exists, than it will never return anything. If you're i > int.MaxValue you could throw an exception, because more than 2,147,483,646 files with the same name looks like an exception to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, it can be OK to `throw` at the end of a method body (as in "we should have never gotten to this point") but it's somewhat unusual.

In this specific case it's obvious that control flow can easily reach the end of the method body -- this will happen if all of the `File.Exists` checks succeed. Now me and you "know" that this is practically impossible, but it is not mathematically impossible and that's enough for the compiler to give an error.

So how should one appease the compiler here? Well, any method has a *contract* under which it operates. This method's contract includes that the method will find an unused filename, copy the source file there and return the path to the caller.

However there are things outside your control that can cause the method to be unable to satisfy this contract, in which case you have to somehow communicate to the caller "I wasn't able to do what you expected me to". This somehow is by throwing an exception.

Comment: Thanks. By the way I modified your answer about the image name modification but leave it in my `"Must learn how to do it"` repository :)